# border-box not working if i give big padding/border

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div, where i need to keep the width & height constant and should not vary because of border & padding applied to it. I used `border-box` property. It is working upto some extend

```
div{
      border:1px solid black;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

but failed in extreme case.

```
div{
      border:60px solid black;
      width:100px;
      height:100px;
      -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

This is actually online tool where user will give the border. So he can give any number but I want to prevent the div to grow with border/padding.

Is there anyway to prevent it either with CSS or javascript? Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: it because your border size is bigger than your width and height

Answer (score 0):

Well, the border will show on the left and right/top and bottom -- each being 60px, so that's 120px of border size total.  The only way you'd be able to force the sizing to stay within 100px is to use JS to force the border to be <= width/height divided by 2.

Comment: how this formula works if width/height given in %, this will vary with parent height.

Comment: @DyapaSrikanth You'd have to calculate the width and height.

Answer (score 0):

it because your border size is bigger than your width and height

> The specified width and height (and respective min/max properties) on this element determine the border box of the element. That is, any padding or border specified on the element is laid out and drawn inside this specified width and height. The content width and height are calculated by subtracting the border and padding widths of the respective sides from the specified ‘width’ and ‘height’ properties. As the content width and height cannot be negative ([CSS21], section 10.2), this computation is floored at 0.

REFERENCE

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-ui/#box-sizing

Answer (score 0):

Other than with JavaScript, there is no way to cap border width per se.  Possible CSS-based solutions involve faking it.

For example, you could wrap a `div` around your bordered boxes with `max-width` and `max-height`, like this: http://jsfiddle.net/3k9Ac/  (That's not necessarily a great solution!)

Or you could build "borders" from other HTML elements, attaining the appearance of a border without being hampered by CSS mechanics--but if you're going that deep you might as well just use a little JavaScript.

Validating user input is really just the simplest and easiest approach.  And you don't necessarily have to display an error message when users exceed reasonable border widths--instead, whenever user input exceeds a chosen maximum (say, 10px) you just default to that max.

Comment: what if width/height given in %?